# After Backup and Sync tried to delete a file, I can't delete it manually

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, google-backup-and-sync, hidden-file

My access to a folder in my Google Drive was removed, and I had synced it with my Windows file system using Backup and Sync. The folder should have been removed, however, Backup and Sync is giving me an error that I can't fix. There is one tiny file left in the folder, but I can't delete it manually, because Windows tells me that the item cannot be found (even though it displays in Windows Explorer).

[image: Error with deleting a file]

I have restarted a few times since this error started, so Backup and Sync has restarted. How should I delete the file or resolve the error?

Comment: Have you tried Safe Mode?

Comment: Shutdown backup and sync. Rename the file to “a.txt” and then try to delete it. For one thing the length of your path and file name are pushing the limits of what explorer allows. It also starts with a `.`. Renaming it should fix that problem. You can also hold the shift key and right-click the file and choose copy as path. Then go to an administrative command prompt and type `del “<filename>”` where you will paste the path you copied in place of <filename>. Do this after you rename it if you are still having trouble.

Comment: @Appleoddity I have now quit Backup and Sync. Trying to rename the file gives the same "Could not find this item" error. Running `del "filename"` returns "Cannot find path "path" because it does not exist.

Comment: @Ramhound no. It's a virtual machine.

Comment: A first step is to run `chkdsk /f` on the drive just to make sure the file system is healthy. Then go from there.

Comment: @ahorn - You can boot into Safe Mode even if you are using a virtual machine.   That isn't a reason NOT to attempt to use Safe Mode to delete the file.  Any event sounds like the file, based on the "cannot find path ..." error, the file is actually already deleted.